# Trivia: Game from movie "Knight Moves"

Tags: film

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 d6 2. d4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. Be3 c6 5. Qd2 b5 6. Bd3 Nf6 7. Nf3 Ng4 8. Bg5 h6 9. Bh4 Qb6 10. h3 Nf6 11. O-O g5 12. Bg3 Nh5 13. Bh2 Bxd4 14. a4 b4 15. a5 bxc3 16. bxc3 Bxf2+ 17. Rxf2 Qc5 18. e5 Ng7 19. exd6 exd6 20. Re1+ Be6 21. Nd4 Nd7 22. Nxe6 Nxe6 23. Rxe6+ 23... fxe6 24. Bxd6 Qxa5 25. Bg6+ Kd8 26. Be7+ Kc8 27. Qd4 Rg8 28. Bf7 Rd8 29. Bxd8 1-0
```

My GoogleFu, usually very strong, left me. Do you have any idea where the game[s] in the movie ["Knight Moves"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104627) come from, especially the one given? Neither Wiki, nor IMDB, nor LiChess database, nor chessgames.com, nor wild goose googling returned any useful information (or I overlooked it).

Comment: If it could be of any use, the chess advisor seems to be some [Marty Kolt](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0464406/). I haven't found much on google, and [some of the results](https://prod-www.tcm.com/tcmdb/person/1110885%7C0/Marty-Kolt/) aren't available in my country (?).

Comment: Three games in this movie, all of them displaying a level of chess you'd expect from a 1700. A waste of time. They got about everything chess-related wrong; Gardés, adjournings, blunder by GM Lutz, patzering analysis by his second, the joy of winning against terrible battle chess, another silly adjourning; and - tada! - the clou to the crimes related to squares without information which piece moved; just ridiculous, I'm afraid. Oh and how often he gets laid; unheard of in chess!

Comment: @PeterFischer: You bet the film (and the game I posted) got the deserved roast in our club zine :-)